# Oracle query to find rows in a table that have the same values for columns A,B, and C but different values for column D

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I would like to find rows in a table that have the same values for columns A,B, and C but different values for column D.

I meant that values in column a are the same for column A, values for column B are the same. etc.

If you have an employee table, I need rows that have employees with the same department, same supervisor, different locations

Comment: ... `WHERE a = b AND b = c AND a <> d`

Comment: I meant that values in column a are the same for column a, values for column b are the same. etc. If you have an employee table, I need rows that have employees with the same department, same supervisor, different locations.

Comment: @OPost You should edit you question when providing additional details. I've done it for you. Please review that change.

Comment: ... in addition, you should definitively provide both some sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: @OPost, if you provide sample input data and expected output as suggested, you'll probably get an answer. Right now your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right:

```
select *
  from YOUR_TABLE t
 where (t.a is not null and t.a = t.b and t.b = t.c and t.a != t.d)
    or (t.a is null and t.b is null and t.is null and t.d is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If these columns are NULLable/Optional, then you might would like to Use NVL or any other NULL handling function. As One NULL value is not equal to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to find which department/supervisor combinations have multiple locations then you can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select department, supervisor, count(distinct location) as locations
from employee e
group by department, supervisor
having count(distinct location) > 1;
```

If you want all data from the rows that are in any of those departments then you *could* use that as a subquery, but that means hitting the table twice. You can use an analytic count instead:

```
select id, department, supervisor, location
from (
  select e.*,
    count(distinct location)
      over (partition by department, supervisor) locations
  from employee e
)
where locations > 1
order by id;
```

... where `id` can be replaced with any fields you want from the underlying table, or omitted entirely if you just want to know which locations are involved.

The inner query gets the original data from the table and adds a column which has the number of (different) locations for the department/supervisor in that row, across the whole result set - that's the analytic part. The outer query then just filters out those which only have a single location.

[Quick SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/185db/2) with made-up data.

It would be more meaningful to you if you'd included your actual table and sample data in the question.